# debian8 iptables stop command wont work

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, iptables

hello people first post on superuser so im sorry if its pretty bad
anyway im working with a debian8  vps and im trying to stop iptables using command

```
service iptables stop
```

but it comes up with a output of 
    `Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.`

also tried using the command
    `service httpd stop`

and get a output of 
`Failed to stop httpd.service: Unit httpd.service not loaded.`

Comment: Why do you think you are running iptables?  Do you have an apache web server installed?  What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 0):

Well, whatever the place you have read about `service iptables stop`
was referencing a severely outdated information because
the direct support for the SysV RC-script was removed from the
`iptables` package in 2002 (!)—to cite the changelog of it:

> iptables (1.2.7-8) unstable; urgency=low
>
> - corrected -dev include dirs
> - removed init.d, /var/lib/iptables, and debconf-ization
> - added Suggests: ipmasq
> - rewrote README.Debian
>
> -- Laurence J. Lane   Sat,  7 Dec 2002 14:31:40 -0500

(See that `init.d` bit?)

What you need instead, if the `iptables-persistent` package,
which is a framework to save/restore `iptables` rules, and which
depends on the `netfilter-persistent` package, *which* does provide
a `systemd`-unit file—see the [`netfilter-persistent(8)` manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/netfilter-persistent).

(Well, I'm saying about Stretch, which is Debian 9,
but Jessie (Debian 8), [has this package, too](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/netfilter-persistent)).

Have fun.